# WSO2 ESB registry Resources List

Tags: registry, endpoint, wso2, wso2-esb

Hi i need some help in this issue:

For many reason i have to save some endpoints in my "/_system/config" registry.

In my code i need to get the list of all of them.
I know i can get one resource programmatically using the code in the link below and previoulsy knowing its key:
http://vvratha.blogspot.it/2013_02_01_archive.html

In particular i'm referring to:

```
Registry regInstance = synapseMsgContext.getConfiguration()
                .getRegistry();

Object obj = regInstance.getResource(new Entry ("Key"), null);
```

How can i get all the /_system/config entries List?
Really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try like;

```
 regInstance.getResource(new Entry ("conf:/"), null);
```

Comment: Yes indeed it was my first try. It returns a null object. In the /_system_config/ i registered 1 enpoint with name LBEndpoint (its key is conf:/LBEndpoint) - regInstance.getResource(new Entry ("conf:/LBEndpoint"), null); returns the right value - while - regInstance.getResource(new Entry ("conf:/"), null); - returns null. Do i miss anything?